# OrderedMap wrapper class does not work

Tags: javascript, wrapper, immutable.js

I've created below wrapper class in JS. While trying to call `set` method by `new MaxOrderedMap(3).set('Adam', 'hello');`. It does not get called ovreridden method which I've created in below class. Can anyone help here?

```js
import { OrderedMap } from 'immutable';

export default class MaxOrderedMap extends OrderedMap {
  constructor(size) {
    super();
    this.maxSize = size;
  }
  set(key, value) {
    const map = this.size >= this.maxSize ?
      this.rest() : this;
    return map.super.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as mentioned here: https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/301.

You can use this project that actually wraps an immutable instance inside another object: https://github.com/philpl/extendable-immutable